# What is the equivalent word to oenology for the study of, knowledge of or expertise in alcoholic drinks and making them?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, food

Apologies in advance, I am no linguist and don't know the proper terminology for things.

I am looking for a collective word to describe someone who is interested in alcohol, makes cocktails, brews, distills, ferments, bartends, and drinks.

I don't mean mixology, which specifically refers to the making of cocktails, nor do I mean oenology/enology/viticulture/viniculture which all relate to wines.

Common suggestions I've found online are bacchanalia, debauchery, libations, bibulous (edit: this was grammatically incorrect, Anton is correct that it would be bibulousness or bibulousity), and victuals. These are unsuitable as they either refer to excessive drinking of alcohol, or are too vague.

The comments seem to agree that the specific word doesn't exist, but I am very happy to see your suggestions.

Comment: Good question. Difficult to answer. Free Dictionary gives meaning for **bibulosity** but associates it with too much alcohol so it is not quite right for your required meaning. Similarly with **bibulousness** as defined in Lexico. So I leave these suggestions as comment rather than answer.

Comment: I am afraid the context you provide is no context. "Showmanship" seems to have nothing to do with eat and drink. You might just as well say he has an interest in "stamp collecting". And your understanding of "cuisine" seems to differ from mine and most dictionaries, e.g. "a style or method of cooking, especially as characteristic of a particular country, region, or establishment." And the only drink that complements cuisine is wine, which you reject. The word you are after almost certainly does not exist, but that is no reason to worry — you can always explain what you mean in a phrase.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for taking the time to comment. I understand that you have butted heads with others in this forum, so I appreciate you taking the time to help out. (Enter does not do a line break, okay.) The example was to provide context not towards the definition of the word I seek, but the type of word I was searching for. How someone might be interested in cuisine (i.e. Studying different cultures cooking), or interested in stamp collecting as you provided. I reiterate that I am no linguist, hence why I defer to anyone else's judgement

Comment: alcohol and spirits.

Comment: Further explanation is that I am trying to describe the interests of a man who is interested in beer, wines, spirits, bartending, bars, cocktails, inventing cocktails, brewing, distilling, and drinking alcohol, all collectively. I could have sworn I'd seen a word describing such once, but everyone here agrees that there isn't one, so I am perfectly happy to settle for a substitute someone else has provided.

Comment: Perhaps the question title can be "What is the equivalent word to oenology for the study of, knowledge of or expertise in alcoholic drinks and making them?". Possibly excluding wine/beer as they include fermentation and differ from spirits. They have special terminology already, but can be included also for an all-encompassing term. I'll leave it to OP. The question body has good details.

Comment: I have tried to clarify best I can. I reiterate that I'm certainly not a linguist, and anything I edit will still have problems. I hope this helps people understand my intention. I appreciate all of the suggestions so far. Thank you for the title suggestion ermanen

Comment: A connoisseur in fine spirits and wine  OR [fine wines and spirits](https://www.harrods.com/en-gb/departments/harrods-food-halls/fine-wine-and-spirits)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an established word as it is a broad concept. There are specialized terms like *oenology* / *enology* (the study of wine and winemaking, 'vinology'), *mixology* (the skill of mixing cocktails and other drinks), *zythology* (the study of beer and beer-brewing, 'beerology'), *zymurgy / zymology* (the study of the biochemical process of fermentation and its uses) and these terms are more established.

However, **liquorology** would be an apt, easy-to-understand neologism. There is also a website about alcoholic beverages (liquors) with the same name. Moreover, **liquorist** is a more established word already. Even, *[ciderology](https://www.theciderologist.com/what-is-ciderology/)* was coined for the study, teaching and championing of cider.

<sub>Note that, in a very few sources, *liquorology* is used as a term in clinical chemistry.</sub>

*OED* definition of *liquor*:

> Liquid for drinking; beverage, drink. Now almost exclusively *spec.*, a drink produced by fermentation or distillation. ***spirituous liquor***, liquor produced by distillation; spirits. ***vinous liquor***, liquor made from grapes; wine. See also *malt liquor n.*

*Liquor* is usually used for spirits where beer, wine and cider are excluded but it can serve as an all-encompassing term for all alcoholic drinks as well.

To define the person, there are the terms *liquorist* and *alcoholist*. The definitions in *Urbandictionary* (which is not credible but good for  colloquialisms, neologisms and slang) are close to what you are asking for:

> [alcoholist](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Alcoholist): An expert at alcohol. Like a specialist~ a professional. Someone who is a specialist at alcohol. Unlike the term "alcoholic", which has a negative connotation, an "alcoholist" is someone who is a specialist at alcohol. They are unlikely to be a drunk, but more akin to a connoisseur of alcohol. This is a compliment, and a term of respect and camaraderie.
>
> [liquorist](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Liquorist): A person who is interested, either professionally or as a hobby, with the collecting, mixing, history, production, discussion and, of course, enjoyment of spirits and cocktails

However, the definitions in *OED* are different and *alcoholist* can have a negative sense:

> [alcoholist](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4711?redirectedFrom=alcoholist#eid): Originally: an advocate of the freedom to drink alcoholic drinks, a person who is against prohibition (prohibition n. 4b) (now *historical*). In later use also: a person addicted to alcoholic drink.
>
> [liquorist](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/108933?redirectedFrom=liquorist#eid):  One who makes liqueurs.

*OED* lists the uncommon adjective [*liquorish*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/108932#eid39281462) also:

> Fond of or indicating fondness for liquor.

---

**Other options:**

- If you follow the Greek route like *oenology*, you can come up with *oenopneumalogy* or *oenopneumatology* for the study of alcoholic drinks. In Greek, *οινόπνευμα* means alcoholic drink/spirit and it is:

> from οίνος (*oínos*, “wine”) +‎ πνεύμα (*pnévma*, “spirit”), a calque of French *esprit-de-vin*. - [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BD%CF%8C%CF%80%CE%BD%CE%B5%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%B1)

Note: *Oeno-* is from the ancient Greek *οἶνο-*, combining form of *οἶνος* wine.

[*Pneumatology*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pneumatology) was coined before also for the study of spiritual beings and phenomena etc.

- *Ethanology* is yet another neologism appears in some related sources in Google Books. It is from *ethanol*, a colorless liquid, which is the intoxicating constituent of liquors. The website *ethanologydistillation.com* defines *ethanology* as:

> The Science, & Art of Distillation.

- *Distillery* is the process of distilling or the establishment for distilling. However, *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/55665?redirectedFrom=distillery#eid)* has the obsolete sense for the art. It might serve as a term for the interest in the process of distilling alcohol.

> The action or art of distilling; = distillation *n.* 3. *Obsolete.*

There is also *The Institute of Brewing and Distilling (IBD)*:

> is an industry trade association for brewers and distillers, both in the United Kingdom and internationally. [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institute_of_Brewing_and_Distilling)

- *Alcohology, inebriology* and *spiritology* have different meanings, apparently.

> alcohology: (sociology) The study of the effects of alcohol; on living organisms, people or social environments. - [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alcohology)

> inebriologist: (n.)one who studies the process of getting drunk. -
> [*Urbandictionary*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=inebriologist)

*Inebriologist* also appears in the book [Eugenics, Human Genetics and Human Failings](https://books.google.es/books?id=TQuAAAAAQBAJ&pg=PP37&dq=inebriology&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGzr_H1Pr2AhUSLBoKHZq-DmoQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=inebriology&f=false) by Pauline Mazumdar.

> spiritology: The studying of spirits, spirit worlds, and other spiritual things is known as spiritology. - [*the-otherworld.fandom*](https://the-otherworld.fandom.com/wiki/Spiritology)

> spiritology: from The Century Dictionary. 
> *noun* Same as pneumatology, 3. - [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/spiritology)

- Yet another neologism: [*boozology*](https://www.google.com/search?q=boozology&rlz=1C1VDKB_enCA994CA994&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP-9OxqvD4AhWlQ_EDHbjkANoQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1536&bih=746&dpr=1.25) from *booze*, slang for alcoholic drink.

Comment: The term *liqour* rarely includes beverages which have been fermented but not distilled.

Comment: Liquor (or a spirit) is an alcoholic drink produced by **distillation** of grains, fruits, vegetables, or sugar, that have already gone through alcoholic fermentation. *From your link, **emphasis** mine.*

Comment: These words **can** be used for that purpose, but, to avoid misleading future visitors to this page, it should be made clear that none of them would be as readily understood as *cuisine*.

Comment: The book [_The Art of Distilling Whiskey and Other Spirits: An Enthusiast's Guide to the Artisan Distilling of Potent Potables_](https://books.google.es/books?id=hmmZhoyyrYoC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=spirits+equivalent+of+oenology&source=bl&ots=Tc5eqVUGJ8&sig=ACfU3U06EQmij6OJ9jpTSStliiE34xLXvg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsveevmvv2AhX5hf0HHQk3BOcQ6AF6BAg4EAM#v=snippet&q=distillation&f=false) [by Bill Owens (Editor), Alan Dikty (Editor), Fritz Maytag (Foreword)] describes "distillation" as an art form also.

Comment: The term _liquorist_ appears in dictionaries and books related to liquors in Google Books as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that an important issue is whether you are talking about a professional, such as a bartender or distiller, or merely someone with amateur level expertise, or someone with a passion? I think it's unlikely you'll find a dictionary word for someone with an amateur level of expertise in alcohol.

Answer (score -3):

Wine is, of course, made by fermenting the many domestic varieties of grapes most often by using the yeast found naturally on the grape. Grapes were developed from wild grapes. Each grape variety most often gives its name to the wine and a person who has become expert, and who through careful experiment has produced many delightful vintages and is an expert in the selection and production of various wines is known as an oenologist.
Fermentation produces alcohol from the sugars found in grapes. Wines rarely exceed 12% alcohol naturally though this may be boosted by certain processes. Another name for alcohol is ethanol.

On the other hand ethanol is also made stronger by a two step process. The ethanol, or spirits, is firstly produced by fermenting grain or potatoes and the resulting liquor is distilled to produce a liquid of a higher alcoholic content, possibly up to 40%.There is no word for an expert in producing an alcoholic drink by this process. We could invent one such as ethanoligist which is not in any dictionary. It should not be confused with ethnologist which is a word for man who studies various races. The word ethnic which often means foreign is derived from that latter word.

Methanol or wood alcohol is produced in the same way by using wood instead of grain or potatoes and is poisonous but useful for industry.

Comment: Why did you post (another) new answer for this? It looks like you're just expanding on your existing answer, so you should instead [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/587177/edit) it